# how to replace the deprecated android.text.format class?

Tags: java, android, time, gregorian-calendar

how can i implement the code below using the GregorianCalendar.
Thanks.

```
Time dayTime = new Time();
 dayTime.setToNow();

int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(),dayTime.gmtoff);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly ?